# where I can deploy strapi for production?

Tags: strapi

I have made a simple comercial project where i used my own cms just for help client upload photos on his page. Its very primitve so i decided to use strapi.io because of better UI/UX. 

My question is where I can deploy strapi. Server where site is hosted doesn't support node.js so it has to be external server. I'm thinking about Heroku but I don't know if it will work and how it should handle img files. It will be nice if solve of this problem won't generate additional costs.

Please, help!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a DB hosted, you could look at using [Mlab](https://mlab.com/) which is cloud database service that hosts MongoDB.

There is a useful Strapi blog post that walks you through deploying it to Heroku here: [Deploying a Strapi API on Heroku](https://blog.strapi.io/deploying-a-strapi-api-on-heroku/)

Comment: Thanks for answer! I will check both.

Comment: Did anyone try deploying Strapi to Zeit Now or Netlify?

Comment: Would also love to know if anyone deployed to Netlify if i will not find it I might try it and share my experience.

Comment: You need a service that will host the server. Zeit & Netlify only host static sites.
Try Heroku, DigitalOcean, AWS, Azure

Comment: mlab is now owned by MongoDB Atlas, they have a similar shared server plan https://www.mongodb.com/pricing

Answer (score 2):

[From their documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment.html#hosting-provider-guides)

1. Heroku
2. AWS
3. Digital Ocean
4. Google App engine

Answer (score 0):

Containerising [strapi application](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/installation/docker) can help you deploy it to any [cloud hosting platforms](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/deployment/hosting-guides).

Answer (score -1):

There was a service called Redhost (redhost.cloud) which specialized in Strapi server hosting.

Comment: The link is wrong. It goes to a domain that is for sale. Please edit your answer so you don't receive negative feedback.